# PyTorch multiprocessing is filling up shared memory. Is there any way to manually invoke torch_shm_manager to garbage collect?

Tags: python, pytorch, multiprocessing

I'm trying to process input data in parallel so it can be loaded into a PyTorch dataset.  However, when it reaches ~20,000 data points or so, the parallel processes crash claiming it can't allocate any more shared memory.  When I look at `/dev/shm`, it's created about ~80,000 files that haven't been cleaned up.  I've solved this in the past by simply using multithreading instead of multiprocessing, but the parallelization gets throttled with multithreading (I'm assuming GIL woes).

I've tried chunking the input data and starting a new `Pool` object for every chunk, as well as `del` ing the return value after it's been added to the full list, but still the number of files in `/dev/shm` piles up and causes the program to crash.  Here's an un-chunked version of my code:

```
import torch
#I have to use file_system because the number of file descriptors exceeds OS limits
torch.multiprocessing.set_sharing_strategy("file_system")
from glob import glob

def processData(fname):
    #Tensor magic goes here, a list of tensors is created from the file at fname and returned 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    datadir = "/path/to/dir"
    processedData = []
    #I hope to eventually use this with CUDA tensors, but for now I'm having issues with CPU
    torch.multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")

    p = torch.multiprocessing.Pool(8)
    for result in p.imap_unordered(processData, glob(datadir+"*.txt")):
        processedData += result
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

I'm not sure why it's creating so much shared memory in the first place, as the only thing being transferred between processes is the returned list of tensors.  Any ideas on how I can either signal to PyTorch it's ok to garbage collect the shared memory or to prevent PyTorch from using so much shared memory in the first place?

Comment: Can you try this with python's multiprocessing `Pool`? This could be general python multiprocess issues and not torch-specific. You can also look into the [datasets](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/index) library which uses Arrow to get around python multiprocessing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't as the output for the processData function is a PyTorch object (specifically PyTorch geometric's Data object), so I have to import torch, and PyTorch overwrites the standard python library on import.